# How to run few testcases or a testsuite from commandline using marathontesting tool (MarathonITE)?

Tags: testing, jruby, gui-testing, marathontesting

I want to run multiple testSuits or testCases via commandline or batch mode using marathontesting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marathon/Marathonite can accept a list of tests on the command line. Suppose you have a test structure like follows (under the TestCases folder):

```
test_1
test_2
folder_1
folder_1/test_1
folder_1/test_2
```

You can run marathon as follows:

```
marathon -batch <project-folder> # Runs all tests
marathon -batch <project-folder> test_1 # Runs only test_1
marathon -batch <project-folder> test_1 test_2 # Runs test_1 and test_2
marathon -batch <project-folder> folder_1.test_1 # Runs only folder_1/test_1
marathon -batch <project-folder> folder_1.AllTests # Runs all tests from folder_1
```

For more details see http://marathontesting.com/documentation/?section=executing-tests-in-batch-mode. Though the user guide is for marathonite is valid for marathon also.